# Translation of question about how to use a certain expression, '몇 살 먹었다'

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate the following:

> Can the expression "몇 살 먹었다" be used only among friends, or can I use it with people I met recently who I don't know well?

Here is my attempt:

> 몇 살 먹었다 라는 칠문은 친구들과만 사용할 수 있어? 좀전에 잘 모르는 만난 사람과 이 말 사용해도 돼?

But I don't know how to say it in a natural way. Could you please correct me?

Comment: "몇 살 먹었냐"라는 질문은 친구들한테만 사용할 수 있어? 전에 잘 모르거나 오래만에 안 만난 사람한테 이 말을 해도 되겠어?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A native speaker I asked suggested only small changes:

> "몇 살 먹었다" 라는 **질문**은 친구들에게만 사용할 수 있어? **아니면** 좀 전에 **만난 잘 모르는** 사람**에게** 이 말을 사용해도 돼?

- added quotes to match the usage of '라는' (or if you don't want to use quotes, you could say *몇 살 먹었냐는 질문*)
- corrected 칠문 to 질문
- added 아니면 as a more explicit 'or'
- put '좀 전에 만난' together to make the meaning clearer
- changed 과 to 에게, as that's more appropriate for asking a question

Comment: 네, 알겠습니다! 정말 감사합니다!

Comment: 친구들과만 is a little bit awkward, I suppose. [몇 살 먹었다는 질문] is weird because "몇살 먹었다" is not form of question. [for asking a question] is ambiguous explanation . I think it's not a big deal but to be more exact, it should be [for using the words to someone]. I mean, the point of "에게" in this sentence is "to". I agree the other analysis.

Comment: @TINGCHOE maybe I should say '친구들에게만' to be consistent?

Comment: 친구들에게만 is good to hear.

Comment: @TINGCHOE though I can see that "몇 살 먹었다" isn't itself a question, I assumed that "몇 살 먹었다" 라는 질문 made sense because it's a kind of 'infinitive' or 기본형, which would become a question when you add the question endings? I could be wrong.

Comment: @topomorto Forget about grammar stuff here. "몇 살 먹었냐는 질문" is good to hear because "몇 살 먹었냐" is a "질문". "몇 살 먹었다는 질문" is weird to hear because "몇 살 먹었다" is not a "질문".

Answer (score 5):

> "몇 살 먹었다" 라는 **표현**은 친구들[하고만or한테만] 사용할 수 있어? **아니면** 좀 전에 만나서 잘 모르는 사람[에게or한테] 이 말 사용해도 돼?

*"몇 살 먹었다" is not 질문.

You can ask someone's age like

1. 몇 살이세요?
2. 연세가 어떻게 되세요?

"연세" is honorifics of "나이". So 2. is more polite expression. Both are already honorifics so you can use for everyone.